# Money to credit algorithm: decreasing precision gives a correct result?

Tags: algorithms

I wrote an algorithm that receives **money** (let's say I work with Euros, for the sake of discussion) in a decimal form as a parameter, and returns **credit** as an int.

- €1.99 equals to 5 hours of credit
- 5 hours = 18 000 seconds
- 1 second = 1 credit
- 5 hours of credit equals to 18 000 credit

The algorithm works like this:

1. Divide input money by 1.99
2. Multiply previous result with 18 000

#### Example

**Convert €3.98 into credit**

1. 3.98 / 1.99 = 2
2. 2 * 18 000 = 36 000

Result: €3.98 equals 36 000 credit (i.e. 10 hours *worth of credit*)

Nothing confusing in this example, let's try one where `input credit % 1.99 != 0`

#### Example No.2

**Convert €4.78 into credit**

1. 4.78 / 1.99 = 2.40201005025
2. 2.40201005025 * 18 000 = 43236.1809045

Result: €4.78 equals 43236 credit. **This is wrong!** The result should've been 43200, which is 12 hours in seconds (12 * 3600)

However, when I **decrease** the float precision, I get a **correct** result:

1. 4.78 / 1.99 = 2.40
2. 2.40 * 18 000 = 43200

**My question is**, can someone explain to me why do I get the correct result when I decrease precision to only two decimal points?

Here's the minimum reproducible code (written in PHP):

```
/**
 * Calculates how much credit did the user buy.
 * €1.99 gives 5 hours, which is 18000 credits (cause 1 second = 1 credit).
 * Returns string to avoid int overflow.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public static function moneyToCreditAmount() : string {
    $moneyAmount = 4.78;

    $credit = bcdiv((string) $moneyAmount, (string) 1.99);
    $credit = bcmul($credit, (string) 18000);

    return $credit;
}
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your calculations ... Who says 43200 is the correct result? The book?

Comment: @Bram28 Thanks for bringing this up, I haven't explained this part properly.  I am testing it by using 12 hours as a known value (in a real world application, I only have access to the money input parameter). The reason why 43200 is the correct result is because (i) 5 hours = 18 000 credits (ii) 12/5 = 2.4 (iii) 2.40 * 18000 = 43200. (iv) 12 hours = 432000 credit. Does it make sense?

Comment: I see how 43200 credits = 12 hours ... But that does not equal 4.78 euros

Comment: Are you saying it actually equals €4.78xxxx ?

Comment: No, it equals 2.4*1.99=4.776

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in the calculations, as Bram28 pointed out. The exact value to purchase 12h worth of credit, as Bram28 pointed out, is 4.776€. As I assume for practical purposes the amount paid must not contain fractional cents, so this is rounded to 4.78€.

However, if you calculate the value of 1cent, using the 5h is worth 1.99€ relation, you get 1cent buys you $5h/199\approx90.452s$ worth of credit. So if a customer pays 4.78€, he is getting 12h worth of credit (that would cost him 4.776€ nominally) and the additional 0.4cents he paid is worth $\approx0.4*90.452=36.1808s$.

That's why your program gives you 43236 credits, that is 36s longer than you expected. Your price for 1s (equal to 1 credit) is so small ($\approx0.011$cents), that you cannot reach every positive integer amount of credits if you disallow fractional cent values. It turns out that the smallest reachable credit value $\ge 43200s$ (12h or more) is 43236 (12h and 36s).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation.